# Hive - InvocationTargetException null

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, cloudera-cdh, apache-sentry

I am trying to connect hive with beeline or hue so i am getting below error

```
2015-01-01 11:56:18,312 ERROR sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:253)
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:1)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.baseOpen(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.access$000(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:77)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport$1.run(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport$1.run(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:99)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.open(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:99)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient.<init>(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:151)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.SimpleDBProviderBackend.<init>(SimpleDBProviderBackend.java:52)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.SimpleDBProviderBackend.<init>(SimpleDBProviderBackend.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.getAuthProvider(HiveAuthzBinding.java:247)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.<init>(HiveAuthzBinding.java:88)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.<init>(HiveAuthzBinding.java:81)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.HiveAuthzBindingHook.<init>(HiveAuthzBindingHook.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HookUtils.getHooks(HookUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:995)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:988)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:98)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:163)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.runOperationWithLogCapture(HiveSessionImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:168)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:316)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1373)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1358)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:608)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
        ... 47 more
2015-01-01 11:56:18,313 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hive/d1.cluster.com@CLUSTER.COM (auth:KERBEROS) cause:sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
2015-01-01 11:56:18,313 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver: FAILED: InvocationTargetException null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.getAuthProvider(HiveAuthzBinding.java:247)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.<init>(HiveAuthzBinding.java:88)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.authz.HiveAuthzBinding.<init>(HiveAuthzBinding.java:81)
        at org.apache.sentry.binding.hive.HiveAuthzBindingHook.<init>(HiveAuthzBindingHook.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.hooks.HookUtils.getHooks(HookUtils.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getHooks(Driver.java:1162)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:440)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:995)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:988)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:98)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:163)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.runOperationWithLogCapture(HiveSessionImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:222)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatement(HiveSessionImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatement(CLIService.java:168)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:316)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1373)
  at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1358)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:608)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1567)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.open(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:99)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient.<init>(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:151)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.SimpleDBProviderBackend.<init>(SimpleDBProviderBackend.java:52)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.SimpleDBProviderBackend.<init>(SimpleDBProviderBackend.java:48)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:221)
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:297)
        at sentry.org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:1)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.baseOpen(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport.access$000(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:77)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport$1.run(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:101)
        at org.apache.sentry.provider.db.service.thrift.SentryPolicyServiceClient$UgiSaslClientTransport$1.run(SentryPolicyServiceClient.java:99)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        ... 37 more
```

I have found temporary resolution :

If i restart hive service everyday then it's working fine but every day i have to restart.

I want permanent solution. Could anyone please help me to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is not with Hive, rather with your kerberos credentials.The tickets generated by Ticket Granting Service stay alive for a specific number of hours after which they expire. Before running hive, you need to run kinit to generate your TGS ticket. That way you will not have to retsart Hive service everytime.

A simple test would be to run the klist command before and after running your hive service.

Comment: But is it feasible to run kinit everytime. I have set up renewal time for krbtgt 7 days.

Comment: Not sure if krbtgt renewal will help here. You can take a look at the below link: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/v4-3-0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_17.html